# Center flow chart horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, diagrams, pstricks

I have the following flow chart but it appears uncentered.  How can I center it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\psframebox[linearc=5mm,cornersize=absolute]{%
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.6,colsep=0.5]
\psovalbox[fillstyle=solid]{Begin} &
\psframebox[]{ChIP-seq} &
\psframebox[]{align to genome} &
\psdblframebox[framearc=.4,fillstyle=solid]{Find peaks} &
\psdblframebox[framearc=.4,fillstyle=solid]{Thresholding} &
\psdblframebox[framearc=.4,fillstyle=solid]{Analysis} &
\psframebox[]{stop} 
\ncline{->}{1,1}{1,2}
\ncline{->}{1,2}{1,3}
\ncline{->}{1,3}{1,4}
\ncline{->}{1,4}{1,5}
\ncline{->}{1,5}{1,6}
\ncline{->}{1,6}{1,7}
\end{psmatrix}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\newline` is in this line of your code: `\psframebox[]{stop}\\\`. Just remove the `\\\`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As frabjous already mentioned, the image is just too big and either image or margins require adjustment.

But there's trick how you can center oversized images: use `\makebox`. This way even your wide image gets properly centered:

```
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\psframebox[linearc=5mm,cornersize=absolute]{%
\begin{psmatrix}
  ...
\end{psmatrix}
}}
```

Answer (score 6):

As near as I can tell the only reason it isn't centered as it is that it is too large to fit within the margins. You have several options:

- Scale the image down (sent the fonts smaller and the dimensions as well)
- Change the paper size or margins with something like the geometry package
- Put the page or the document as a whole in landscape mode

It is difficult to tell which of these options is the best without knowing more about the context.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was informative +1.  I would prefer to center the image anyways through a hack rather than scale down in this case.