# shifting (0,0) to new coordinate Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using Tikz to draw a wide graph but starting from left and after reaching the middle of the graph the nodes fall outside of page. I tried playing with scale but the graph distorts and  texts inside nodes does not conform to new scale well. So I need to move the (0,0) to some place left, say (-5,0) to have enough space to draw the rest of graph. How can I do that?
I saw the shifting command in the manual but it was command specific and converting the coordinates is somehow overkill.

> How can I shift the (0,0) to a new coordinate, say (-5,0)?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to do exactly this, then put whatever you want to move in a scope, and provide the `shift` option to said scope (the curly braces are necessary so the comma isn't thought to separate options).  Something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-5,0)}]
    ... graph goes here ...
  \end{scope}
  ... other code goes here ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, if your *whole picture* is wider than the text, this won't help.  In that case, you should be able to use a negative horizontal space:

```
\hspace*{-5cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ... picture goes here ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, if you want centering, you could check out [some of the solutions to a similar problem with over-wide tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4926/table-will-not-center-and-it-is-spilling-off-the-right-side-of-the-page), such as surrounding it in a zero-width box.

Comment: Is there another possibility to shift the origin than in a environment? I tried `\scope[shift={(0,-5)}]`. It is no surprise, that it didnt work. I want to shift it several times throughout the TikZ-picture.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I don't know, off the top of my head – sounds like a great new question to ask here!

Comment: For cross reference: here is the new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353855/shifting-origin-0-0-to-new-coordinates-in-tikz