# Shifting origin (0,0) to new coordinates in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw some explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/shifting-0-0-to-new-coordinate-tikz) how to shift the origin. But at the end of the environment it is reverted.

What I want is a command that shifts without reverting it. I thought this might be possible with nodes. But this is just an idea for a work around.

I tried the command `\scope[shift={(0,-5)}]` and it - of course - didn't work.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
\draw [->, very thick] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
\scope[shift={(0,-1)}]
\draw [->, very thick] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
\scope[shift={(0,-1)}]
\draw [->, very thick] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
```

resulting in three chained arrows. I'm aware that this might be achieved in other ways, but some command like this would be in my opinion very useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure of the usefulness of this approach, but `\tikzset` can alter most of tikz parameters from the point it appears on, so...

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->, very thick] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
    \tikzset{shift={(0,-1)}}
    \draw [->, very thick] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
    \tikzset{shift={(0,-1)}}
    \draw [->, very thick] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Where can I find this list of parameters. I havent found it in the documentation (yet).

Comment: Any option you can pass to a scope, or even to a tikzpicture can be set via `\tikzset`, so for example, `rotate=90`,  `x=0.5cm`, `every node/.style={whatever}`, etc.

Comment: The usefulness of this approach is, that I can create tikz pictures which change with different parameters (i.e. `\textwidth`). This way I can make full dynamic diagrams. i.e. If I change the middle arrow in size or direction, the bottom arrow follows.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I understand, but I think that dynamic diagrams (i.e: which can adapt to layout changes) can be created also with the help of tikz `positioning` library (and/or `calc` expressions, named coordinates, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

```
\draw [->] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
\begin{scope}[yshift=-1cm]
\draw [->] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
\draw [->] (0, 0) -- (0,-1);
\end{scope}
```

[image]

*Note:*

- as experienced TeX.SE user you should provide complete small document and with this helps people who would be willing help you.  Above example I test in my `tikzpicture` test-bed, which setting can differ from your document, so I didn't provide them.
- `scope[<options>]` is wrong syntax, correct is `\begin{scope}[<options>] ... \end{scope}`
- each shift of scoped part of image code is relative to coordinate `(0,0)`, sou you need accordingly increase shift amount, otherwise the second shifted image part will overlap previous one.
- for shift in only one direction you can use `xshift=...` or `yshift=...`

Comment: I think the OP was aware of the proper use of `scope` but he wondered if it would be possible to "permanently" change the origin, so that each new shift is accumulative, so you don't need to mentally track the "total" shifting, hence my answer.

Comment: I know that it is wrong. If you read the question carefully, I dont want to use an environment. The solution with tikzset is what I was looking for. `scope` was just how it Should work.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz, I read your question carefully and didn't found anything what you now claim, that it is in question ... and, if you know, that `scope[...]` doesn't work, why than you use it? You should then emphasize that this is pseudo code ...

Comment: @JLDiaz, it seems that you have crystal ball by which you can see in questions more than we others can :-)  ... I like to have one, at list for while :-)  :-)