# How to make a graphic fill the rest of a given space?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, margins

Sometimes I use a figure numbering style in which each number is placed to the left of a figure. When using this formatting, I try to make sure that the space occupied by a given number and figure is confined by the same margins as those set for the main text. This creates a nice alignment effect. I have tried to achieve it in LaTeX by using two `minipage` environments inside a `figure` environment and some simple mathematics:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{minipage}{\1cm}
{\Large(3)}
\end{minipage}%
\newlength{\pic}
\setlength{\pic}{\columnwidth}
\addtolength{\pic}{-\1cm}
\begin{minipage}{\pic}
\includegraphics[width=\pic]{blue}
\caption{Caption}
\label{blue}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

This code, however, didn't work quite as I expected: as you can see in the picture below, the figure sticks out onto the right margin.

[image: Figure]

How can I ensure that the figure fills up the space next to the number while being neatly aligned with the body of the text?

(Incidentally, I would also be very grateful for some suggestions on how to make the number and the picture aligned at the top.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Also check out [Is there a way to measure the remaining space of a line of text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17349/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-remaining-space-of-a-line-of-text) for the automatic measuring of the remaining space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by spurious spaces in your code. Line endings are taken as spaces which add a little bit more distance between the `minipage`s. Simply place `%` at the lines ending with `}` or `{`. Alternatively place an `\unskip` direct before the second `minipage`. The following code should work:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \begin{minipage}{1cm}
    {\Large(3)}
  \end{minipage}%
  \newlength{\pic}%   % should be in the preamble!
  \setlength{\pic}{\columnwidth}%
  \addtolength{\pic}{-1cm}%
  \begin{minipage}{\pic}
    \includegraphics[width=\pic]{blue}%
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{blue}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

You can also write it a little simpler by using `\dimexpr` (introduced by eTeX):

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \begin{minipage}{1cm}
    {\Large(3)}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-1cm\relax}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{blue}%
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{blue}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

Note that inside a `minipage` the `\textwidth` refers to the `minipage` width.

Comment: @Marin Scharrer It works like a charm, thank you so much! In fact, I experimented with `%` before but obviously didn't put enough percent signs ;) And I'm sorry about the sloppy code.