# Get the Length of the Rest of a Line

Tags: line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to measure the remaining space of a line of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17349/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-remaining-space-of-a-line-of-text)

I have some text and want to put a \hrulefill at the end following by a period.  However, if the text of the line comes too close to the end of the line, the rule is omitted and just a period results -- or -- a new line is created, the rule is omitted, and the line begins with a period.

How can I determine if there is enough space at the end of the line for a sizeable enough hrulefill of some specified length?

Comment: As @Ben said this is actually a duplicate in the general case. However, if Phil's answer does it for you as well I would accept it and the question could stay, under a different, more specific title.

Answer (score 6):

How about the following (using ideas from the command `\qed` in amsart.cls):

```
\newcommand{\myrulefill}{\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hrulefill
  \hbox to 1em{\hrulefill}.}
```

That guarantees you at least 1em of hrulefill (you can change that 1em to some other length, of course), and prevents the hrulefill from being on a line by itself.  You'd just put the command `\myrulefill` at the end of your paragraph.

Comment: I implemented this and it works like a charm!  Thanks for everyone's help.  Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @Doug: No problem. This is a specific case and therefore not an exact duplicate. Please accept this answer then by clicking the tick mark on the top left of it. Thanks.