# Make an \fbox of the remaining line width in `exam` class

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, exam

I'm writing a math test in the `exam` class, and I want to make framed boxes for the students to write their answer in. I've tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17349/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-remaining-space-of-a-line-of-text), but the box exceeds the right page margin by 6.79999pts. What's going wrong here?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\whatsleft}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page text area.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\addpoints
\question[8] \emph{Regn ut:}
\begin{parts}
    \part[2] $6-(-4) = $ \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\whatsleft}\vspace{2em}\hfill\end{minipage}}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to take account of the box padding

```
\begin{minipage}{\whatsleft-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
```

but you don't need tikz for this really, you could just use classic TeX leaders.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\whatsleft}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page text area.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\addpoints
\question[8] \emph{Regn ut:}
\begin{parts}
    \part[2] $6-(-4) = $ \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\whatsleft-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}\vspace{2em}\hfill\end{minipage}}
\end{parts}

\question[8] \emph{Regn ut:}
\begin{parts}
    \part[2] $6-(-4) = $ \vrule\leaders\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hrule width.1pt\vskip\normalbaselineskip\hrule\kern-\dp\strutbox\hrule width0pt depth\dp\strutbox}\hfill\vrule\mbox{}\\dd
\end{parts}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to solve this with "classic TeX leaders"? =)

Comment: @Holene example added (sorry I had a meeting:-)

Comment: @Holene, David Carlisle *IS* a "classic TeX leader!"