# How to calculate width of remaining part of line

Tags: boxes, titlesec

I wish to create section heading using `titlesec` like image

[image]

But I have some  difficulties in determining the width of remaining of line to include blue box containing section label,  my method consist of subtracting length of gray box from `textwidth` but it did not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\myl}
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!90}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80}

\newcommand{\graybox}{\colorbox{mygray}{\strut \color{white}Section~\thesection}}

\settowidth{\myl}{\graybox}


\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}%
{\graybox}{.5ex}{\colorbox{myblue}{\makebox[\dimexpr \linewidth-\myl-2\fboxsep-.5ex][l]%
{\strut \color{white}\large\bfseries #1}}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right now you are measuring `\graybox` in the preamble. I think you should move the line `\settowidth{\myl}{\graybox}` in the last argument of `\titleformat`, before `\colorbox{myblue}...`.

Comment: @campa Perhaps make your suggestion an answer, as it fixes the problem nicely, even after a `\setcounter{section}{100}` changes `\thesection` width.

Comment: Thanks @campa your comment fix the problem, can you  post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The computations are somewhat similar to those in the other answers, but this solution also copes with unnumbered sections and long titles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\sectionlabelbox}
\newlength{\sectionlabelwidth}
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!90}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80}

\newcommand{\sectionlabel}{%
  \sbox{\sectionlabelbox}{\colorbox{mygray}{\strut\color{white}Section~\thesection}}%
  \global\sectionlabelwidth=\wd\sectionlabelbox
  \usebox{\sectionlabelbox}%
}
\newcommand{\sectiontitle}[1]{%
  \colorbox{myblue}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\sectionlabelwidth-2\fboxsep-0.5ex}{
      \raggedright\strut\color{white}#1
    }%
  }%
}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\large\bfseries\global\sectionlabelwidth=-0.5ex }%
  {\sectionlabel}
  {.5ex}
  {\sectiontitle}

\begin{document}

\section{A test}

\setcounter{section}{9}

\section{Another test}

\section{Another test, but with a title that is so long it has to be
split across lines}

\section*{A further test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a modification where the grey box has the same vertical size of the blue box.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\sectiontitlebox}
\newlength{\sectionlabelwidth}
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!90}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80}

\newcommand{\sectiontitle}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\sectionlabelwidth}{%
    \colorbox{mygray}{\strut\color{white}Section~\thesection}%
  }%
  \sbox{\sectiontitlebox}{%
    \colorbox{myblue}{%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\sectionlabelwidth-2\fboxsep-0.5ex}{
        \raggedright\strut\color{white}#1
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \colorbox{mygray}{%
    \vrule height \dimexpr\ht\sectiontitlebox-\fboxsep\relax
           depth  \dimexpr\dp\sectiontitlebox-\fboxsep\relax
           width 0pt
    \color{white}Section~\thesection
  }%
  \hspace{0.5ex}%
  \usebox{\sectiontitlebox}%
}

\newcommand{\sectionstartitle}[1]{%
  \colorbox{myblue}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep}{
        \raggedright\strut\color{white}#1
    }%
  }%
}

\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]
  {\large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\sectiontitle}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
  {\large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\sectionstartitle}

\begin{document}

\section{A test}

\setcounter{section}{9}

\section{Another test}

\section{Another test, but with a title that is so long it has to be
split across lines}

\section*{A further test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to have the grey box always the same height as the blue box? It would look nicer, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard Your wish is my command. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg:Thanks, my Lord! That is quite simple and elegant indeed. Actually, the really nicest (but it's my personal taste) would be a simple coloured \fcolorbox with no coloured background around the label.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Is there a way to measure the remaining space of a line of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17349/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-remaining-space-of-a-line-of-text)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\myl}
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!90}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80}

\newcommand{\graybox}{\colorbox{mygray}{\strut \color{white}Section~\thesection}}

\settowidth{\myl}{\graybox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\currentsidemargin}{%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
    \oddsidemargin%
    \else%
    \evensidemargin%
    \fi%
}

\newlength{\whatsleft}

\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Helper nodes
    \path (current page.north west) ++(\hoffset, -\voffset)
    node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight]
    (pagearea) {};


    \path (pagearea.north west) ++(1in+\currentsidemargin,-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
    node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight]
    (textarea) {};

    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (textarea.east) in
    [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries}%
{\graybox}{.5ex}{\measureremainder{\whatsleft}\colorbox{myblue}{\makebox[\dimexpr\whatsleft-2\fboxsep][l]%
{\strut\color{white}\large\bfseries #1}}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section{blub}

\setcounter{section}{10}

\section{blub}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]