# How to stretch table or minipage to fill remaining space?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to make a document like this:

[image]

Since there's quite a lot of such sections, I want to make a new command like `\textwithline{}{}` so I can then type

```
Author: \textwithline{Joe Shmoe}{First name, Last name}

This author's editor: \textwithline{Billy Willy}{First name, Last name}
```

in my document.

Note the important features:

- The line must fill all available remaining space
- The text above and below the line must be centered on the line
- The text on the left is variable length (or may be blank)

What is a good way of making such a command? I have tried:

- `tabular` with `\hfill` but it doesn't actually stretch the table
- `tabular*` but it doesn't "give room" to the text on the left
- `minipage` but that requires me to hard code width every time
- `\uline{\hfill Billy Willy \hfill}{\hfill First name, Last name \hfill}` with `\centering` but then text below line is not centered on the line, but on the page

Comment: Related: [How to calculate width of remaining part of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312581/5764)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\textwithline[2]{{%
\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}%
\hrulefill
\raisebox{5pt}{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}%
\raisebox{-12pt}{\makebox[0pt]{#2}}%
\hrulefill
\par
\bigskip}}

\begin{document}



Author: \textwithline{Joe Shmoe}{First name, Last name}

This author's editor: \textwithline{Billy Willy}{First name, Last name}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using [`linegoal`](//ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) to calculate the remaining width of the line (given by `\linegoal`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linegoal}

\newcommand{\textwithline}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linegoal}
    \centering\strut #1 \\[-.7\baselineskip]
    \hrulefill \\[-.1\baselineskip]
    \centering\small\footnotesize #2
  \end{minipage}\par
  \addvspace{.5\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

Author: \textwithline{Joe Shmoe}{First name, Last name}

This author's editor: \textwithline{Billy Willy}{First name, Last name}

\end{document}
```

Since `linegoal` uses a label-ref-like system (thanks to [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)), any changes in width would require you to compile at least twice before the width settles.