# Auto linefeed of node text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

`\node` by `tikz` is used to get an effect of text highlight. It's all right except that the node text can not automatically linefeed. Is there a better way to achieve this?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,picture,eso-pic,calc,etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\hspace{20em}yellow green wood \tikz[baseline] \node[fill=gray!20, anchor=base,inner sep=0pt] {yellow green wood yellow green wood }; yellow green wood 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you could reach your needs without TikZ: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a look at a few related questions and might have a set-up that does what you want. Two ingredients:

- The `\measureremainder` command provided by [this user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17808/172926). This allows us to record the length of the remaining whitespace in a line before using a tikz node.
- The `varwidth` environment from the varwidth package. This is a minipage of variable width that we can use *inside* a node.

The minimal preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % \measureremainder
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % \measureremainder
\usepackage{varwidth} % varwidth environment

\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page text area.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newlength{\whatsleft}  % length to be used in nodes
```

Firstly, immediately before calling `\tikz` save the length of the remaining line with `\measureremainder{\whatsleft}`. You could then set the `text width` property of the node to this value:

```
\begin{document}
    This is a very long line of example text before a node.
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}
    \tikz[baseline] \node[fill=gray!20, anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, text width=\whatsleft] 
    {This is example text inside a node.}; 
    This is a long line of example text following a node.
\end{document}
```

This makes the text in the node wrap around:
[image: output1]

But means that the node will always span the rest of the line, which may not be desired:

```
\begin{document}
    This is a long line.
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tikz[baseline] \node[fill=gray!20, anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, text width=\whatsleft] 
    {This is example text inside a node.}; This is a long line of example text.
\end{document}
```

[image: outpu2]

(the difficulty is that a tikz node have no equivalent of a `max width` property).

We can get around this by using `\whatsleft` in the arguemnt of a `varwidth` environment:

```
\begin{document}
    This is a long line.
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tikz[baseline]\node[fill=gray!20, anchor=base,inner sep=0pt] 
    {\begin{varwidth}{\whatsleft}
        This is example text inside a node.
    \end{varwidth}};
    This is a long line of example text following a node.
\end{document}
```

[image: output3]

All said and done, I don't think tikz nodes were really designed for this purpose - have you tried using the ordinary `\fbox` and `\parbox` commands? (Info on these can be found on the [LaTeX/Boxes Wikibook page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#parbox,_minipage,_and_pbox).)