# How can I customize a theme independent note page? (beamer)

Tags: beamer, margins, columns

I would like to create a custom note page in `beamer` which sould look like this

[image]

However, the layout of this note page will vary greatly depending on the current theme settings. If I am to change the theme settings the note page will change significantly, the note page layout is likely to change as well. For instance if I am to change the left and right text margins to 15mm, the page will look like this

[image]

I think that most of this is due to the behavior of `columns` environment. I mean that it inserts a space automatically between the multiple columns which is usually what is desired. If I am able to set the distance between two columns to very small amount (such as 3mm), then the empty space in the pic above will be removed. However, I still want to achieve many things

- The left edge of the slide preview should have 0mm margin with respect to the left of the page
- The height of the rotated preview slide should stretch from the very top of the page to the very bottom while maintaining the aspect ratio. This would leave an unknown amount of horizontal space for the next column. However, I still do not know how to calculate this space in order to properly determine the dimensions of the adjacent columns
- The margin of the `\insertnote` contents with respect to the left of the page should be have an exact value such as 5mm. Also, the top margins of `\insertnote` should have pre-specified value such as 3mm

Even though I got very close to the requirements above, I still do not how to precisely achieve them. Further, it would be very great bonus if `\insertnote` contents could be automatically shrunk to fit in their columns (in case they did not with their original size).

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

    \setbeameroption{show notes}
    \newcommand{\itemShowMoreContents}{\item<+->}
    \newcommand{\presentUncoverMoreContents}{\uncover<+->}



    \usecolortheme{wolverine}
    \useoutertheme[]{split}
    \useinnertheme{rectangles}

        \setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}

        \newlength{\sidebarWidth}
        \setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.1\paperwidth}

        \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}



    % ===== Cuztomize the note page =====

        \newlength{\widthNotePageSlideMax}
        \setlength{\widthNotePageSlideMax}{0.2\paperwidth}
        \newlength{\widthNotePageContents}
        \setlength{\widthNotePageContents}{0.6\paperwidth}
        \setbeamertemplate{note page}{

            \begin{columns}

                % The slide figure
                \column[t]{\widthNotePageSlideMax}

                    \adjustbox{rotate=90, max height=0.98\paperheight,  frame}{\insertslideintonotes{1}}

                \column[t]{\widthNotePageContents}
                % The Notes
                \justifying
                \insertnote

            \end{columns}

                                    }
        \setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\normalsize}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually without Alert}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
        %
        \presentUncoverMoreContents{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

        \begin{description}
            \itemShowMoreContents[Rigid] Rigid
            \itemShowMoreContents[Cheap] Cheap
                        \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate} \blindtext} \\
            \itemShowMoreContents[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \itemShowMoreContents[Self-Starting] Self-starting
            \itemShowMoreContents[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
            \itemShowMoreContents[Something goes here] Extra contents
        \end{description}

        \vspace{\fill}

        More content

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automatically make the text column fill all the available space left by the image, you can use a nice little trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17808/36296

```
\documentclass[
aspectratio=169, 
xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\useoutertheme{split}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=2mm, text margin right=2mm}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}

\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.1\paperwidth}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

% ===== Cuztomize the note page =====

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newlength{\whatsleft}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin%
    \adjustbox{rotate=90, max height=\paperheight,  frame,valign=t}{\insertslideintonotes{1}}%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
    \addtolength{\whatsleft}{-5mm}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\whatsleft}%
        \justifying%
        \insertnote%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{note page}{size=\normalsize}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually without Alert}

\begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
%
\uncover<+->{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

\begin{description}[<+->]
\item[Rigid] Rigid
\item[Cheap] Cheap
\note<+>{\blindtext} 
\item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
\item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
\item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
\item[Something goes here] Extra contents
\end{description}

\vfill

More content

\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great solution, but there are still two questions: 1. how can I get the slide preview to be vertically centered in case that I modified its width. For instance `max height=0.9\paperheight`, 2. how do I force `\insertnote` contents to shrink to the visible space if it was too large?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh 1. Have a look at the align options of the adjustbox package. 2. This is a very bad idea, especially when you scale down text it will be hard to read. Better manually use a smaller font size, this will give you letter shapes which are easier to read at small sizes.