# Measure the length of an \hskip with one compilation

Tags: boxes, glue, measure

I am trying to measure the width of an `\hskip`. I have tried something like

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
a
\skip_horizontal:N 10pt plus 1fill
\box_set_to_last:N \l_tmpa_box
b\par

\the\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But `\l_tmpa_box` appears to have zero width. I thought that an `\hskip` becomes a box once it's typeset, but maybe I am misunderstanding something.

In any case, I know how to use `\tikzmark` to measure the width with two compilation passes. However, I am wondering if it can be done directly in one pass.

Comment: `\hskip` inserts a glue, not a box. For more details refer to the TeXbook chapters 11-12.

Answer (score 2):

The function `\box_set_to_last:N` is essentially the TeX primitive `\lastbox` and a call such as

```
\box_set_to_last:N \l_tmpa_box
```

is the same as

```
\setbox\l_tmpa_box=\lastbox
```

Here's what the TeXbook says about it:

> The bottom line of the table above refers to `\lastbox`,
> a primitive operation that hasn't been mentioned before. If the last item
> on the current horizontal list or vertical list is an hbox or vbox, it
> is removed from the list and it becomes the `\lastbox`; otherwise
> `\lastbox` is void.  This operation is allowed in internal vertical
> mode, horizontal mode, and restricted horizontal mode, but you cannot use
> it to take a box from the current page in vertical mode. In math modes,
> `\lastbox` is always void. At the beginning of a paragraph,
> ‘`{\setbox0=\lastbox}`’ removes the indentation box.

So your attempt fails, because the last item in the current horizontal list is a skip.

However, also

```
a\setbox0=\lastbox\hskip 10pt plus 1fill
```

will result in `\box0` to have zero width; more precisely, it will be void, because the last item isn't an hbox or a vbox, but a character.

You *cannot* detect the final amount of a skip when a paragraph is being absorbed, because stretching or shrinking happen at a later stage when the paragraph is split into lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance what the right hand side of the line will contain then you can do as follows.

The [tabto](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabto/tabto-doc.pdf) package defines a command `\tabto` that jumps to a specific position in a line, and a length `\CurrentLineWidth` that contains the line width at the point of calling the command. Furthermore, `\tabto` stores the position where it was last called in a length `\TabPrevPos`. Therefore, as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541683/89417 (answer by the package author), you can 'jump' to the current width (which causes no change in the position), then do the `\hskip`, then calculate the width of the skip by subtracting the width of the right hand side and the first position from the linewidth. This calculation needs only a single compilation pass.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabto}

\newlength{\hskiplen}
\newlength{\firstpos}
\newlength{\secondpos}
\newsavebox{\rhs}
\begin{document}
\sbox{\rhs}{xyz}
abc\hskip10pt plus 1fill xyz

abc\tabto{\CurrentLineWidth}\hskip10pt plus 1fill\setlength{\firstpos}{\TabPrevPos}\setlength{\secondpos}{\linewidth-\wd\rhs-\TabPrevPos}\usebox{\rhs}

first position: \the\firstpos

second position: \the\secondpos

\setlength{\hskiplen}{\secondpos-\firstpos}length of hskip: \the\hskiplen

width of rhs: \the\wd\rhs
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this essentially circumvents the original problem, because you are not measuring the hskip itself, but all other elements in the line. It is difficult to actually measure the box created by `\hskip` with fill, because the width is dependent on the rest of the line so the box is not yet available after the actual command (I think...). You could try if LuaLaTeX can provide more information on the complete list of boxes, see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Pandora%E2%80%99s_%5Chbox%3A_Using_LuaTeX_to_Lift_the_Lid_of_TeX_Boxes for some pointers.