# How to create multiple dotted lines

Tags: macros

I want to create multiple dotted lines, I found this code on the internet

```
\newcommand{\Pointilles}[1][3]{%
        \multido{}{#1}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\dotfill}\\[\parskip]}
        }
```

The problem is that the first dotted line comes too close to last one in the paragraph and adding some vertical space manually as shown below

```
some text her. \\[4mm]
\Pointilles[2]
```

may cause the vertical space to appear after the dotted lines.
At the same time I would like to be able to specify the line spacing for the dotted lines.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241137/how-can-i-fill-vertical-spaces-with-dotted-horizontal-lines help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways of achieving your goal. The following merely builds on what you've already created:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand{\Pointilles}[1]{%
  \par\nobreak
  \noindent\rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}% Provides a larger gap between the preceding paragraph and the dots
  \multido{}{#1}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\dotfill}\endgraf}% ... dotted lines ...
  \bigskip% Gap between dots and next paragraph
}
\begin{document}

Here is some text.
\Pointilles{5}

Here is some more text.
\Pointilles{3}

Here is some final text.
\Pointilles{2}

\end{document}
```

A minor adjustment to `\Pointilles` could allow you to stretch the content using an adjustable `\strut`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}

\newcommand{\Pointilles}[2][3]{%
  \par\nobreak
  \noindent\rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}% Provides a larger gap between the preceding paragraph and the dots
  \multido{}{#2}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{#1\baselineskip}\dotfill}\endgraf}% ... dotted lines ...
  \bigskip% Gap between dots and next paragraph
}
\begin{document}

Here is some text.
\Pointilles{5}

Here is some more text.
\Pointilles[1.5]{3}

Here is some final text.
\Pointilles{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Get misplaced lines within enumerate environment; The first line comes indented and exceeds other lines on the right.

Comment: @user22432: Ahhh, well thanks for providing more context. In the future, please provide all details relating to your problem in the form of a minimal example that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your setup. Instead of `\endgraf` in my code, consider using ``\\``. You may have to play around with the `\baselineskip` values.

Comment: Excellent! Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{loopcntr}

\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{\forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{FlushLeft}
\noindent Here is some text.
\rpt[3]{\noindent\vbox spread 1cm {}\null\xleaders\hbox to 2mm {\hss . \hss}\hfill \null\newline}
\end{FlushLeft}

\begin{FlushLeft}
\noindent Here is some more text. \newline
\rpt[3]{\noindent\vbox spread 1cm {}\null\xleaders\hbox to 2mm {\hss . \hss}\hfill \null\newline}
\end{FlushLeft}

\begin{FlushLeft}
\noindent Here is some final text.\newline
\rpt[5]{\noindent\vbox spread 0.5cm {}\null\xleaders\hbox to 1mm {\hss . \hss}\hfill \null\newline}
\end{FlushLeft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a comprehensive solution and welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It gave me some `Underfull \hbox` warnings.