Automating drawing horizontal lines until the end of the page
I have a page filled with text (arbitrary vertical height) and would like to fill the rest of the page with horizontal lines. So far my solution is to manually adjust how many lines are drawn:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mylines}[1]{% number of lines from the bottom up
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#1}{
      \draw[lightgray] ($(current page.south)+(-0.56\textwidth, 4+0.833333*\i)$) -- ($(current page.south)+(0.56\textwidth, 4+0.833333*\i)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\mylines{21}
\clearpage
\blindtext[2]
\mylines{16}
\end{document}

Is there a more automatic (but not too complicated/involved) solution so I wouldn't manually have to determine how many lines fit in the remaining part of the page on every page?
The only related question I could find is this (but it seems rather involved). Perhaps there is (by now) a more elegant solution to implementing the 'looping until the end of the page' procedure.
Ideas: Alternatively, perhaps there is a tikz-based solution that always fills the page but sets the lines transparent as soon as they overlay text (but tikz probably also doesn't know where there is text on a page...).
In my non-minimal working example, the text is contained in an environment. Perhaps one could determine the height of that environment and that would determine how many lines fit in the remaining space.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241137/how-can-i-fill-vertical-spaces-with-dotted-horizontal-lines/241139#241139 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392074/vertical-fill-with-horizontal-line/392077#392077.

Why trees for this?!

You can use the grid operation with xstep=0 to draw only horizontal lines. Then start a \newline and draw a grid to the bottom right of the text area. The node current page text area is useful here, and requires the package tikzpagenodes.
You must compile twice.

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand{\linestobottom}{\newline\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
    \draw[lightgray] (-.5,0) grid[xstep=0, ystep=.8333] ([shift={(.5,-1)}]current page text area.south east);
}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\linestobottom
\clearpage
\blindtext[2]
\linestobottom
\end{document}


Hi, great! Is there a solution that starts from the south and draws the grid upwards in order to keep the first line at the bottom at a fixed distance from the page number (and rather have a variable vertical distance from at the top from the text)? I tried to draw the grid with negative ystep and interchanged the drawing direction but the grid disappears.

This is the current version of the fillwith package. See Vertical fill with horizontal line and/or How can I fill vertical spaces with dotted horizontal lines? for history.
This requires a single compilation. It supports dotted lines, rules and custom styles. The line distance is adjustable, as is the vertical space to be filled by the lines. It can also number the lines, but do note there is a significant performance penalty for line numbering. Colour is supported and it can be used in two column formats.
The original code was due to Harish Kumar, but it has evolved a bit since then. In particular, it now uses mostly expl3.

On first compilation, this will spit out the package fillwith.sty, which you can then put somewhere TeX will find it. Then you can just load it in the normal way.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fillwith}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\fillwith
\clearpage
\blindtext[2]
\fillwith[style=rule]
\end{document}

For rules or dots, it is fast because a single box is created and copied as many times as necessary. When numbering is desired, it is slower because you cannot simply copy boxes if each line gets a new number.
Code:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{fillwith.sty}
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% fillwith.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2021-11-15]
\ProvidesPackage{fillwith.sty}[2024-04-07 04:12:44Z 9989 cfr]
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% copied verbatim, excepting format from Joseph Wright's' siunitx.sty under LPPL
\@ifundefined{ExplLoaderFileDate}{%
  \RequirePackage{expl3}%
}{}
% almost verbatim from siunitx.sty
\@ifl@t@r\ExplLoaderFileDate{2022-02-24}{%
}{%
  \PackageError{fillwith}{Support package expl3 too old}
  {%
    You need to update your installation of the bundles 'l3kernel' and
    'l3packages'.\MessageBreak
    Loading~fillwith~will~abort!%
  }%
  \endinput
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_name_prop { fillwith } { fillwith }

% BEGIN Expl pkg option setup

\keys_define:nn { fillwith }
{
  color .meta:n = {
    colour = #1,
  },
  colour .code:n = {
    \colorlet{fillwithcolour}{#1}
  },
  dotted color .meta:n = {
    dotted colour = #1,
  },
  dotted colour .code:n = {
    \colorlet{fillwithdottedcolour}{#1}
  },
  lliw .meta:n = {
    colour = #1,
  },
  colour .initial:n = gray,
  dotted colour .initial:n = black,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Joseph Wright: from siunitx.sty ; https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64327823#64327823
\providecommand \IfFormatAtLeastTF { \@ifl@t@r \fmtversion }
\IfFormatAtLeastTF { 2022-06-01 }
{
  \ProcessKeyOptions [ fillwith ]
}{
  \RequirePackage { l3keys2e }
  \ProcessKeysOptions { fillwith }
}
\IfFormatAtLeastTF { 2020-10-01 }{
}{
  \RequirePackage { xparse }
  \providecommand \ExpandArgs [1]
  { \cs_if_exist_use:c { exp_args:N #1 } }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BEGIN vars
\coffin_new:N \l__fillwith_line_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l__fillwith_lines_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l__fillwith_tmpa_coffin
\dim_new:N \l__fillwith_ht_dim
\dim_new:N \l__fillwith_rem_dim
\dim_new:N \l__fillwith_line_ht_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__fillwith_line_ht_dim { 0.4pt }
\int_new:N \l__fillwith_cnt_int
% END vars
% BEGIN fns
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \fillwith_style: {}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \fillwith_coffin_tht:N
{
  \dim_eval:n { \coffin_ht:N #1 + \coffin_dp:N #1 }
}
% END fns
\NewDocumentCommand\fillwithset { +m }{
  \keys_set:nn { fillwith } { #1 }
}
\keys_define:nn { fillwith }
{
  cont .bool_set:N = \l__fillwith_cont_bool,
  cont .default:n = true,
  fillwith~ht .tl_set:N = \l__fillwith_ht_tl,
  fillwith~ht .initial:n = 2,
  line ~ nos .bool_set:N = \l__fillwith_nos_bool,
  line ~ nos .default:n = true,
  line ~ nos .initial:n =false,
  style .choices:nn =
  {
    rule , dots , unknown
  }{
    \if_case:w \l_keys_choice_int
    \or: \cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \fillwith_style: { \hrulefill }
    \or: \cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \fillwith_style: { \dotfill }
    \else: \cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn \fillwith_style: { \use:c { \l_keys_choice_tl } }
    \fi:
  },
  style .initial:n = dots,
}
% END Expl pkg option setup

% BEGIN \fillwith_fill:
% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241139/ Harish Kumar
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \fillwith_fill:
{
  \dim_set:Nn \l__fillwith_ht_dim { \medskipamount + \l__fillwith_ht_tl \baselineskip }
  \color{fillwithcolour}
  \if_mode_horizontal:
  \bool_if:NTF \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  {
    \vrule height \l__fillwith_ht_dim depth \c_zero_skip width \c_zero_skip
    \fillwith_style:
    \par
  }{
    \par
  }
  \fi:
  \hrule height \c_zero_skip
  \nobreak
  \setbox0=\hbox to \hsize{
    \skip_horizontal:n { \@totalleftmargin }
    \vrule height \l__fillwith_ht_dim depth \c_zero_skip width \c_zero_skip
    \fillwith_style:
  }
  \cleaders \copy0 \vfill \hbox{}
  \normalcolor
}
% END \fillwith_fill:
% BEGIN fillwith
\NewDocumentCommand \fillwith { s o }
{%
  \group_begin:
  \IfValueT { #2 }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { fillwith } { #2 }
  }
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  }{
    \bool_set_false:N \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  }
  \fillwith_fill:
  \group_end:
}
% END fillwith
% BEGIN fillwithdottedlines
\NewDocumentCommand \fillwithdottedlines { s O { 2 } }
{
  \group_begin:
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  }{
    \bool_set_false:N \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  }
  \keys_set:nn { fillwith } { style = dots, fillwith~ht=#2 }
  \fillwith_fill:
  \group_end:
}
% END fillwithdottedlines
% BEGIN fillwithnolines
\cs_new_protected:Nn \fillwith_nos: % rhybudd: ARAF ! SLOW!
{
  %   \color{fillwithcolour}
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l__fillwith_line_coffin { \linewidth }
  {
    \vrule height \l__fillwith_line_ht_dim depth \c_zero_skip width \linewidth \fillwith_style:
  }
  \coffin_set_eq:NN \l__fillwith_lines_coffin \l__fillwith_line_coffin
  \int_incr:N \l__fillwith_cnt_int
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l__fillwith_tmpa_coffin  { 1.5em} {  \int_to_arabic:n { \l__fillwith_cnt_int } }
  \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__fillwith_lines_coffin {b} {r} \l__fillwith_tmpa_coffin {b} {l} {2.5pt} {0pt}
  \dim_set:Nn \l__fillwith_ht_dim { \fp_to_dim:n { \l__fillwith_ht_tl * \baselineskip }  }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__fillwith_rem_dim { \pagegoal -\footskip - \pagetotal - \l__fillwith_ht_dim  }
  \dim_until_do:nNnn { \fillwith_coffin_tht:N \l__fillwith_lines_coffin } > { \l__fillwith_rem_dim - \l__fillwith_ht_dim }
  {
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l__fillwith_lines_coffin { b } { l } \l__fillwith_line_coffin { t } { l } { 0pt } { -\l__fillwith_ht_dim }
    \int_incr:N \l__fillwith_cnt_int
    \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l__fillwith_tmpa_coffin  {1.5em} { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__fillwith_cnt_int } }
    \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__fillwith_lines_coffin {b} {r} \l__fillwith_tmpa_coffin {b} {l} {2.5pt} {0pt}
  }
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__fillwith_lines_coffin { t } { l } { 0pt } { -\l__fillwith_ht_dim }
  %   \normalcolor
}
\NewDocumentCommand \fillwithnolines { s O { } }
{
  \group_begin:
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  }{
    \bool_set_false:N \l__fillwith_cont_bool
  }
  \keys_set:nn { fillwith } { style = dots, #2 }
  \fillwith_nos:
  \group_end:
}
% END fillwithnolines
\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fillwith}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\fillwith
\clearpage
\blindtext[2]
\fillwith[style=rule]
\end{document}

