# How to define a custom PDF page size without margins and header/footer? KOMAscript

Tags: margins, koma-script, paper-size, geometry

I want to create a PDF file with `pdflatex` which

- has a custom page size: `\pdfpagewidth=680.6pt \pdfpageheight=441.0pt` and
- which will be used completely for typesetting (no margins, no header or footer!)
- which is based on the `scrbook` class

It seems that the `geometry` package might do what I want, but I did not get there yet. Can somebody help?

*Why?*
I want to set the page size to the `textheight` and `textwidth` of my main document (thesis) and then create separately some very large `longtables` which I want to include pagewise with `includegraphics` in the main document.

**Remark:** For easier editing of the tables, I want to be the created PDF in landscape format, so each page will have to be rotated to fit in the main document.
I hope this won't pose any problems. One difficulty I see is the **space for the caption** on the first page of each table.

If you have further **ideas, what might go wrong** or which difficulty I might have overlooked, with my plan, please tell me.

Comment: One idea would be to bring `longtable` to wrap each generated table page in a `preview` environment. This cuts down the page size automatically if the `tightpage` option is used.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: thanks for your comment! I'm not familiar with the `preview` package. What would be the advantage compared to just adding each page of the pdf with `includegraphics` to the main document?

Comment: No, that was meant to crop the pages of the `longtable` to your the `\textwidth` and `\textheight` as you wanted. Anyway, forget about that crazy idea. It turned out that setting the right `geometry` options is way easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following `geometry` options seem to do what you requested (see the manual for more information). I added some test output as well. Note that `\hbox{\rule{680.6pt}{441.0pt}}` doesn't cause an overfull hbox warning and fills one page nicely.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[noheadfoot,nomarginpar,margin=0pt,paperwidth=680.6pt,paperheight=441.0pt,showframe]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

textwidth=\the\textwidth

textheight=\the\textheight

pdfpagewidth=\the\pdfpagewidth

pdfpageheight=\the\pdfpageheight

\newpage\hbox{\rule{680.6pt}{441.0pt}}\newpage


\def\stuff{long & long & long \noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\\}
\edef\stuff{\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff}
\edef\stuff{\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff\stuff}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
    \stuff
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

To fit the caption in you could use `\enlargethispage{<length>}`, where I would goes something from `\baselineskip` to `2\baselineskip` as a good length. Just watch for overfull warnings to see how much you must add. Note that this doesn't make it look better, just makes it fit!

Comment: thanks for your help and for the example! However, for the caption I'm not sure if \enlargethispage will help, as the tables are landscape format, so it is the \textwidth of the page affected and not the height. I could add a `\rule` of width 0pt above each longtable, but then I would have the white space above my table..

Comment: @Martin: How do you create the landscape pages? `\enlargethispage` should be fine with most ways. One other way would be to place the caption using TikZ (see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-is-consume-the-rest-of-a-page/14514#14514 for ideas) or the `textpos` package.

Comment: Scharrer: I'm currently experimenting, how to typeset the landscape pages in my thesis. I think this has to be discussed elsewhere: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/sidewaystable-vs-landscape-environment-for-landscape-tables-spanning-double-pages