# sidewaystable vs landscape environment (pdflscape-package) for landscape tables spanning double pages

Tags: tables, floats, double-sided, rotating, landscape

As explained in several other posts, I'm currently trying to create wide tables.
The document is in portrait format A4, but the tables shall be typeset in landscape format.

As the tables have more rows than would fit on one page, they continue over a doublepage (and often even on the following pages).

I found 2 ways to do what I need:

**`sidewaystable`**-environment: has the drawback that it rotates each table in a way that the upper part shows to the inner margin. This makes sense in general, but not in my case where the table should be readable on the whole double page without rotating the document.

-> is there a way to use sidewaystable with a rotation which is always counter-clockwise?

**`landscape`-environment (`pdflscape`package)**: seems to always rotate counter-clockwise, which I appreciate. However, the whole pdf page is rotated and I wonder if this could lead to problems while printing the document etc.

Comment: What's with `pdfflscape` package? Printing should not be an issue.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: that's what I meant with the landscape environment (sorry, edited my question). Are you sure, that there are no problems with printing, if some pages in the pdf are rotated?

Comment: The PDF viewer should be smart enough.

Comment: Have you considered the longtable environment. It gives good (many pages) tables after several compilations and you won't have to rotate your table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With regard to your first question (`sidewaystable` which always rotates counter-clockwise) -- and quoting from p. 2 of the [`rotating`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) documentation:

> If the ‘`twoside`’ option has been given to the main document class
>   (either explicitly, or implicitly as in the default for book class),
>   the package will rotate sideways figures according to the page number
>   (this requires at least two passes through LaTeX). If you want the
>   ‘`twoside`’ option, but want the figures always in one direction, use
>   the ‘`figuresright`’ or ‘`figuresleft`’ options to the package.

While the quoted part uses the term "figures", the package options are also applicable for (sideways) tables.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
(Table content)
\caption{A table}
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
(Table content)
\caption{Another table}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```