# How to translate this scenario to LaTeX looping macro?

Tags: calculations, loops

I want to slice an image into 8 parts, i.e., 2 rows by 4 columns. Each part is on a single page as follows. The gray frame is the Acrobat Reader background, so don't think it is a part of the output I want to have.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{bald}}
\newdimen\width
\newdimen\height
\width=\wd\IBox
\height=\ht\IBox
\parindent=0bp
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\centering%
%first row
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0\width} {0.5\height} {0.25\width} {\height},clip]{bald}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0.25\width} {0.5\height} {0.5\width} {\height},clip]{bald}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0.5\width} {0.5\height} {0.75\width} {\height},clip]{bald}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0.75\width} {0.5\height} {\width} {\height},clip]{bald}}
%second row
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0\width} {0\height} {0.25\width} {0.5\height},clip]{bald}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0.25\width} {0\height} {0.5\width} {0.5\height},clip]{bald}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0.5\width} {0\height} {0.75\width} {0.5\height},clip]{bald}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={0.75\width} {0\height} {\width} {0.5\height},clip]{bald}}
\end{document}
```

If you need the image to be sliced, here it is.

[image]

I have attempted to translate it using nested `\multido` macros as follows but it did work. I think it is because I have no enough knowledge in doing length manipulation in (La)TeX.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{bald}}
\newdimen\width
\newdimen\height
\width=\wd\IBox
\height=\ht\IBox
\parindent=0bp
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\centering
\multido{\nx=0+0.25}{4}
{%
    \multido{\ny=1+-0.5}{2}
    {%
        \fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,viewport={\nx\width} {\ny\height-0.5\height} {\nx\width+0.25\width} {\ny\height},clip]{bald}}%
    }%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my answer to [Breaking pictures across multiple pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/breaking-pictures-across-multiple-pages/22836#22836) where I do something very similar, just the cutting is done vertically not horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{bald}}
\newdimen\width
\newdimen\height
\width=\wd\IBox
\height=\ht\IBox
\parindent=0bp
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\centering
\multido{\ry=0.5+-0.5, \rY=1.0+-0.5}{2}{%
  \multido{\rx=0.00+0.25, \rX=0.25+0.25}{4}{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[%height=\textheight, makes no sense without width=...
       viewport={\rx\width} {\ry\height} {\rX\width} {\rY\height},clip]{bald}}%
    }\\%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `height` without `width` is used to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: However, it makes no sense. Your paper dimensions are not proportional to the image dimensions

Comment: @xport: I know `keepaspectratio` do you?

Comment: @Herbert: This code can be compiled with neither `xelatex` nor `xetex`.

Comment: @xport: clipping is broken in the xtex driver of graphicx.