# How to make a graphic to continue on next page?

Tags: graphics

I have an article in TeX, The following image describes what I want to achieve!

I know how TeX works "Normally" on graphics, but really this is what I want.

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: This is something I really wouldn't try to achieve.

Comment: [Question related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/breaking-pictures-across-multiple-pages). It says "Unfortunately this doesn't work. Picture environments (picture, tikzpicture, ...) are (horizontal) boxes on there own and LaTeX doesn't break these. I would need to do this by yourself." In that case, you have to split your image by yourself…

Comment: Just cut the image into two using any image editor then include it as two separate images.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need it to be automatically.

Comment: @Gahir you can't really do that automatically in general, TeX has not decided the page breaks at the point the `\includegraphics` happens, and by the time it does decide the page breaks it can not split the image. It's like asking to break the page in the middle of an `X`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but I really need this to be done! I don't know, maybe some scripts, or something other than manually doing it.

Comment: Actually, I want something maybe similar to `‎\allowdisplaybreaks‎`, but for graphics instead of equations!

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreaks` does not allow you to break in the middle of a `\sum` sign or other unbreakable thing, a display is a series of rows with a natural break point between them, normally amsmath explicitly prevents breaking at that point and `\allowdisplaybreaks` just tells it not to do that. An image is completely different, it is like a letter: tex has absolutely no knowledge about its internal structure.

Comment: but what is "this" that you want to do? always split it in half? or would you split of a strip 1mm high if that is what it takes to fill the first page then have a 1mm high image at the top of the second page or...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want the image to flow through pages, as it would in text; like the picture above. (It first occupies the remaining space in the page and flows the remaining part of the image to the next page - As simple as this!)

Comment: @Gahir that is not simple at all it is totally against the way TeX works. You can make an approximation by looking at `\pagetotal` as in the posted answer but it does not really have the right information (it has little information about floats for example as they are added to the page later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
%--------------------------------------------------
\newsavebox\mtbox
\newcommand{\mtgraphics}[1]{%
\sbox\mtbox{\includegraphics{#1}}%
\null%
\dimen255=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax%
\ifdim\dimen255>\ht\mtbox
  \usebox\mtbox
\else
\dimen254=\dimen255%
\dimen255=\dimexpr\ht\mtbox-\dimen254\relax%
  \includegraphics[trim=0mm 1.\dimen255 0mm 0mm, clip=true]{#1}
  \par
  \includegraphics[trim=0mm 0mm 0mm \dimen254, clip=true]{#1}
\fi}
%--------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\mtgraphics{myfoto}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm it works ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8YvL7.png)). Nice !

Comment: @touhami Thanks, it does work! but if you replace `\lipsum` command with normal text, the image flies to next page. (I mean how should I change my text to make it behave like `\lipsum[1-5]`?)

Comment: it isn't really safe to use dimen254 as a scratch register, better to use 0 and 2, or do it inside a group but yes, although this can never be reliable (`\pagetotal` is not accurate at the time you need to look) it is probably the best that can be done for the OPs requirement

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much for your useful contribution.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The trick does not work for _minipage_ environment at all! What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Gahir the whole point about a minipage environment is that it is a box that is guaranteed not to split. So the issue should not arise in a minipage.