# How can I divide a figure in multiple pages?

Tags: graphics

I have a figure that is really high, it would fit well in 3 pages, but currently I have it stretched in one. It's only one PDF (converted from a PNG image) and I cannot find out how to divide it in multiple pages. I have searched in multiple places but I have not found the solution.

What can I do?

**Update** - this is what I have:

[image: Current status]

But I want to have it split in 3 pages:

[image: Goal]

The problem is that I have seen those solutions you link to but they do not respect margins or vertical orientation.

Comment: Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214568/spread-image-pages-in-chapter-opener?lq=1,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right or [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35162/)?

Comment: you can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225658/how-to-make-a-graphic-to-continue-on-next-page/225686#225686

Comment: @cfr as the image fit in 3 pages i think this question is not duplicate at least not duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45104/split-a-scanned-photo-across-multiple-pages-with-a-predifined-splitting-point

Comment: @touhami http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right might have been better? I get confused between these questions which all seem to be doing the same thing but aren't really....

Comment: @cfr i think the OP asks for something like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225658/how-to-make-a-graphic-to-continue-on-next-page (I have a figure that is really high)

Comment: That's similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23860/how-to-include-a-picture-over-two-pages-left-part-on-left-side-right-on-right, isn't it? Or is it the difference between horizontal and vertical splits?

Comment: @cfr yes i think it is vertical splits here.

Comment: @touhami You may be right. The 'stretched' confuses me.

Comment: I have updated the description, since it seemed that it was not correctly explained.

Comment: Razican Or not correctly understood, at least by me :(. That is much clearer. Does the question @touhami linked to help? That seems to actually be doing what you want here?

Comment: The problem with that is that since I'm a newbie, I cannot understand the command to adapt it D:

Comment: The problem with the question is that there is not a minimal example. When there's an example, people are much more likely to show you how to adapt stuff for your case. But when there isn't, they have to start setting the problem up from scratch and that is boring and time-consuming.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I decided to do it in a "not so beautiful way":

```
% Gantt diagram in four pages
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0in 0in 26in 0in, clip, angle=90]{fig/gantt}
    \caption[Gantt diagram of the project.]{Gantt diagram of the project. Continues in next
    pages.}\label{fig:gantt}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[trim=7.82in 0in 17in 0in, clip, angle=90]{fig/gantt}\clearpage
    \includegraphics[trim=16.82in 0in 8in 0in, clip, angle=90]{fig/gantt}\clearpage
    \includegraphics[trim=25.82in 0in 0in 0in, clip, angle=90]{fig/gantt}\clearpage
\end{center}
```

But it works :) thanks!

Edit: Here is how it finally looked:
[image: First page]
[image: Second page]

I had 4 pages for the image, and looked pretty well.

Comment: Could you post a snapshot of what this turned out to look like?  Believe it or not, your "not so beautiful" answer looks like the cleanest code to solve the problem!

Comment: I added the result images :)

Comment: @Razican Where? I don't see either images or alternate text. (Sometimes images disappear, but then I see the alternate text, so I don't think it is that.)

Comment: @Razican Oh, I see. You just put them in the question rather than the answer. I've moved them for you to avoid confusion. It would be nice if you would make your code so that it can be compiled.

Comment: @Razican: Remember to select the answer with a green checkmark, if you accept it.