# How to cut a figure/ break a figure to go over several pages

Tags: graphics, floats, include

My aim is to cut pictures into two halves at the end of a page so that is would be continued on the next page and no space will be wasted.

By document type is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
```

And I include pictures like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{testpicture.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Does someone have an idea how to do that splitting?

Comment: do you want the images to be split into two equal parts, or do you want to have it so on the first page, it tries to fill as much as possible on that page, and then have the rest of the image on the next page?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225658/how-to-make-a-graphic-to-continue-on-next-page/225686#225686

Comment: You can use two figure*[b] and crop the image two different ways.  If you want to wait until an even page, you can use afterpage.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page/281075?s=1|1.3440#281075