# Automatically move `tikzpicture` to the following page if it does not fit current page

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, multicol

### Problem Description

I’d like to automatically move the `tikzpicture` to new page if it does not fit the current page. See the MWE—if you compile it as it is, the `tikzpicture` starts on the current page, but bleeds out the page edge. When this should happen, the whole `tikzpicture` must be automatically moved to the next page (as if you uncomment the `\newpage` command`.

I use `xelatex`.

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[10pt, chapterprefix=false, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1in, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, multicol, lipsum}

\newcommand{\colbreak}{\vfill\null\columnbreak}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    % \newpage
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-2.5cm}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[red, line width=1.6mm] (0,-9) node[below=10] {{Ω}} -- (0,0) -- (1,0) node[above=10] {{0}} node[below=10] {{0}} -- (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above=10] {{Α}} -- (0,0) -- (-1,0) node[above=10] {{2}} node[below=10] {{2}} -- (-3,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \colbreak

        \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22836/121799) is something that allows you to split the tikzpicture.

Comment: why you not enclose to float environment?

Comment: @Zarko, I’m a \*Tex newbie and I have never used a float environment. Anyway, I tried `\begin{figure} .. \end{figure}`, however, I does not work in `multicols` env (`Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside \`multicols' 
environment!`), therefore I tried to put the whole `multicol` env into `figure` env. Though that moved the `tikzpicture` to the following page, however, it is displayed *alone* on that page **and** the next that should be *after* the `tikzpicture`, is moved *before* it.

Comment: @marmot, I don’t want to *split* the `tikzpicture`, I want it to be *always* displayed in whole, therefore when I occurs on the bottom of a page and should it not fit in the remaining space, it should be *automatically* moved to the following page. Also note that the `tikzpicture` has some text in the right column, which also must be always on the right side of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: why you use `multicol`? for two column text you can use option `two column` in your document class, which allow to use  floats.

Comment: That to me an obvious option to make the particular text apear on the righ ofthe `tikzpicture`. The text is kind of description of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Anyway, @Zarko, I don’t to use two column in the whole document, only iwhen necessary. Is this possble with the `two column` option?

Comment: sorry, i just guessing, due to lack of information about your document.

Comment: No problem, @Zarko. I am open to other options, while to output will be same. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to put the `tikzpicture` in a `\savebox` (such that we know its height), [measure the remaining space on the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/121799), compare it to the height of the `tikzpicture` and issue a `\newpage` if it does not fit.

```
\documentclass[10pt, chapterprefix=false, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=1in, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz, multicol, lipsum}

\newcommand{\colbreak}{\vfill\null\columnbreak}%
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/121799
\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
\newsavebox{\TikZPic}
\begin{document}

    \lipsum

    \begin{lrbox}{\TikZPic}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[red, line width=1.6mm] (0,-9) node[below=10] {{AAA}} -- (0,0) -- (1,0) node[above=10] {{0}} node[below=10] {{0}} -- (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3) node[above=10] {{AAA}} -- (0,0) -- (-1,0) node[above=10] {{2}} node[below=10] {{2}} -- (-3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{lrbox}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{-2.5cm}
    \ifdim\ht\TikZPic>\measurepage
    \newpage
    \fi
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \usebox\TikZPic

        \colbreak

        \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works as expected, though I think it would be better not to use the remaining space calculation, as it slows down the compilation, which is not a problem with a two-page document, however, I think it might be a problem when one wants to compile a book.