# Continue to next page without limits and without "Dimension too large"

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, dimensions, capacity

I have been wondering if there is a way to control the size (height and width) that a tikzpicture environment can support for drawing and I have often seen only undefined answers being cited. I'm afraid I may not have searched this answer enough and it exists here on the site, but I would like to know if I can control and extend indefinitely the number of pages a tikzpicture continues to the next page avoiding getting the "Dimension too" error large "? Note: happened once I was able to extend a tikzpicture environment to be drawn on 21 pages (A4), it was the most I could. I always wish I could continue a single tikzpicture for the next unlimited pages (except the hardware's own ability to render the generated pdf display). To do so see the question [Breaking pictures across multiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/breaking-pictures-across-multiple-pages)

Comment: There is a limit on the size of the tikzpicture because the TeX dimensions are limited to about `16384pt`. To have a picture larger than that you'd probably need to change TeX itself...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I know the folder where the TeX files are on my system, such as texmf, but what would be the exact file or files I need to change and which keys or lines of code I need to change if you can help me because I'm not an expert.

Comment: I'm afraid very few people around here would be able to help you with that (I, for one, can't). The limit of `16384pt` is due to the type of variable (32-bit integer) TeX uses internally to represent dimensions. To enlarge that limit you'd need to change _all_ of the variables in TeX's code to 64-bit integers (or more). That's not a trivial (if even fasible) task. What is your use-case? Do you really need such a large picture? I'd suggest you draw a smaller picture, and then rescale it.

Comment: I imagine the extent of the task to accomplish this goal. Answering your question @PhelypeOleinik I am trying to continue a network designed with tikznetwork package https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-network, which involves about thirty layers for now and would still like to continue adding more layers.

Comment: I'm the Jon Snow of Ti*k*Z, so I can't help you there. What I Imagine that would postpone your problem would be some option like `scale=0.5` in the `tikzpicture`, so that every length would be halved and you would (theoretically) be able to make a picture twice as large as your current one. Later you'd need to rescale that with some other software. I imagine you are making some kind of poster, so you could have your printer software rescale your picture... That or somehow split the picture in smaller, more manageable pieces.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik For now I'm grateful, I'll keep researching and trying what advised me :)