# Multiple breakable tcolorbox entities next to each other

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to place some `tcolorbox` next to each other but also provide `breakable` content.

Now without `breakable` the boxes are placed well but won't break the content on a new page:

```
\documentclass[10pt,A4]{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{myone/.style={colback=green,colframe=blue,equal height group=nobefaf,width=\linewidth/4,nobeforeafter}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[myone,title=Box 1]\lipsum\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[myone,title=Box 2]\lipsum\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[myone,title=Box 3]\lipsum\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[myone,title=Box 4]\lipsum\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I introduce `breakable` to `tcbset` then there won't be any grouping anymore:

[image]

Are both functionalities contradicting each other so there won't be a solution at all or did someone found a way to get both to work?

Comment: You could put it in a savebox and use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22836) to break it in pieces that fit on a page each.

Comment: You can use breakable tcolorboxes with paracol, but they aren't a group any more.  In fact, you cannot specify the height for any breakable tcolorbox.