# Measuring the distance from text to the top of the page

Tags: unit-of-measure

How can I obtain a measurement from the baseline of any line of text in a document to top of the body of text on a page?

Comment: I'd probably use TikZ to add a node at the given point; with the y-coordinate of this point and the y coordinate of, for example, `current page.center` you could calculate the length that you want.

Comment: Have a look at the similar question [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page). It's solution can be tweaked to give you the length you need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The length `\pagetotal` is a measure of the accumulated distance from the baseline of the first line of the page. Alternatively, the [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) also allows node placement and coordinate extraction via its `savepos` module. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\newcounter{parcnt} \newcommand{\nl}{\stepcounter{parcnt}\theparcnt}
\begin{document}
\zsavepos{top}\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par \bigskip \bigskip
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par \medskip
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par \smallskip \smallskip \smallskip
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par
\nl\ \the\pagetotal \par \vspace{2cm}
\zsavepos{bottom}\nl\ \the\pagetotal\ \the\dimexpr\zposy{top}sp-\zposy{bottom}sp\relax \quad%
  \smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\pagetotal+1em\relax}}
\end{document}
```

Both the `\pagetotal` and `zref`-labels identify a `191.84995pt` vertical distance to the first base line. As such, I assume `\dimexpr\pagetotal+1em\relax` is what you're after (here `1em`, from a visual standpoint, seemed to represent the first "`\baselineskip`").

Comment: Very good solution, showing both approaches. Shouldn't 1em, be 10pt though? The default for article?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Probably - I wasn't sure where to find the first `\baselineskip` on a page. Any source?

Comment: no it was off the top of my head:). Your calculation is correct, however `\pagetotal` measures from the top of the page (which includes `\topskip`) - not as you indicated. The correction for the rule height is to add `baselineskip-depth` (this is more or less the font size or 1em). This will get affected in certain cases with topskip. Was hoping you could shed a bit more light:).

Comment: This doesn't work for me; `pagetotal` is always 0 (using beamerposter in beamer)