# How to use vfil inside tabularx

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

The `\vfil`s in the following mwe seem to have no effect:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\lipsum[1] & a \vfil b \vfil c\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make this work? What I want is very similar to [How to use the equivalent of a vfill in a tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49510/how-to-use-the-equivalent-of-a-vfill-in-a-tabular-environment) except I don't know a priori what the height of column 1 will be (but it will always be at least the height of the column 2 without the `\vfil`). I suppose I could store the height of column 1 in a macro but is that the best way to do this? Solutions avoiding tabular(x) are also welcome.

Comment: Do you have multiple rows or is it just two side-to-side boxes?

Comment: @egreg I do not have multiple rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to measure the left box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\doubleleftbox}
\newenvironment{doublebox}
 {%
  \begin{flushleft}
  \begin{lrbox}{\doubleleftbox}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr0.5\columnwidth-\tabcolsep}\strut\ignorespaces
 }
 {\unskip\strut\end{minipage}\end{flushleft}}

\newcommand{\changeside}{%
  \unskip\strut\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \usebox{\doubleleftbox}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b][\ht\doubleleftbox][s]{\dimexpr0.5\columnwidth-\tabcolsep}
  \strut\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-3]

\begin{doublebox}
\lipsum[1]
\changeside
\lipsum[2][1-2]\vfil \lipsum[2][3-4]\vfil \lipsum[2][5-6]
\end{doublebox}

\lipsum[4][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]