# Using [H] but with adjustable figure size

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page)

I personally have a problem with letting LaTeX do *all* the layout.  Sometimes, where an image appears ends up being just fine.  But other times, the image is far enough from the referencing text (ie on the next page) that the flow of the document is injured.

I want to use the `[H]` specification from the float package, but I actually *don't* care about the size of these images so much as I care about the placement.  Anything from `0.3\textwidth` to `0.7\textwidth` would be fine with me.

Is there a way to let LaTeX play with the *size* of the image as a variable, while letting me dictate the placement?

Comment: Not really, but you could have a look at [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14512/2975), which might be helpful.