# Force Picture to take up remaining space on a page

Tags: graphics, floats, tikzscale

I have a picture that needs to be presented in as large a format as possible due to its intrinsic size and the fact that the graph is reltively dense with information presenting results at 255 points.

I want to show one graph per page and the code below does this. However on the first page where I also want to include the header Results the graph is pushed onto the next page. How can I change the code so that the header and graph appear on the same page with the graph taking up as much of the remaining space as possible.

```
\Section{Results}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, scale=1]{2002.eps}
 \caption{Error Distributions and Distance between Median Solutions}\label{fig:2.1}
 \end{figure}

 \clearpage
```

Answer (score 2):

If your graph only needs a little bit more space you can change the page dimensions a little bit. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{textheight=240mm} %This increases the 'box' Latex uses for you image
\addtolength{\voffset}{1cm} %This put your header down 
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt} %Puts your page number up

\section{Results}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.9\textheight, scale=1]{image1}
\caption{Error Distributions and Distance between Median Solutions}
\label{fig:2.1}
\end{figure}

\restoregeometry %Don't forget this, else the rest of your article will have the new dimensions
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

The [demo]{graphicx} is only to generate a figure that can be used by everyone here. I hope this helps. Furthermore I changed the scaling of the height of the figure to 0.9. If this is kept at 1 (this is the default value) the whole page is filled and there is no space left for the name of your chapter.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment)

You're not making it any easier for yourself by specifying `width=`, `height=` and `scale=`.  [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics) has more information, but basically setting `width` and `height` would break your aspect ratio if it worked, while setting `scale=1` says don't change the size.  I don't think `\textheight` is what you're looking for either - that's the height of the whole text area on the page.

Try specifying just `[width=\textwidth]` or just `[scale=???]`.

A similar discussion has been had before at [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page) and has an answer, though it's not simple.

Answer (score 1):

This MWE gives two pages, without altering the location of the section header or page number (i.e., without changing page size).  The first has a page number, and shows that if you want the full `\textheight`, there is some overlap with the section heading.  That could still possibly work for you, depending on the content of the figure.

If not, page two also fits the full `\textheight` image on the page, but removes the page number for this page only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\def\IG#1#2{\fboxsep -\fboxrule\relax\fbox{\rule{0ex}{#2}\rule{#1}{0ex}}}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\section{Results}
\vfill\smash{\abovebaseline[-6ex]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\IG{\textwidth}{\textheight}%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight,scale=1]{2002.eps}
 \captionof{figure}{Error Distributions and Distance between Median Solutions\label{fig:2.1}}%
\end{minipage}}}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Results}
\vfill\smash{\abovebaseline[-7.5ex]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\IG{\textwidth}{\textheight}%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight,scale=1]{2002.eps}
 \captionof{figure}{Error Distributions and Distance between Median Solutions\label{fig:2.1}}%
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]