# Scale figure to remaining page height in ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I have a page with some content on it and some remaining space at the bottom of this page.

```
|=========|
| header  |
|---------|
|         |
|  page   |
| content |
|         |
|---------|
|remaining|
|  space  |
|---------|
| footer  |
|=========|
```

I want to place figure which fit exactly in this remaining page space. Picture must be placed at the end of page without page breaking. `\externalfigure[fig][factor=fit]` does not work when height of picture is too high to fit in remaining space, and picture placed on next page.

Comment: Your question lacks some information what exactly you intend to do if the graphic is smaller or larger than the remaining space. This fits the graphic into the remaining space: `\externalfigure[cow][height=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\lineheight\relax, width=\textwidth]`

Comment: I think `\externalfigure[wide.jpg][factor=max,maxwidth=\textwidth,maxheight=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\lineheight\relax]` doing exactly what I want. Could you also say in your answer what is `\pagegoal` `\pagetotal` `\lineheight\relax` and how did you know about?

Comment: `\pagegoal` is the height of the box that TeX aims to fill. `\pagetotal` is the so far accumulated height. You can read up the details e.g. in the TeXbook or [TeX by Topic](http://www.eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html). Aditya already [provided an answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/5245). If that solves your problem I'd suggest to upvote his answer and close this question as a duplicate.