# Insert image so that it fills the rest of the page while not fall below a minimum size

Tags: graphics, scaling, fit, fill

I'm trying to make a command that adds images to page in a way that fill the rest of the page. I'm using code from [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813) and it works. But I noticed that sometimes the image will be very small when there is little space left, so I wanted to make it conditional - if there is more than 1/3 of the page left, fit the image, otherwise just put the bigger image on the next page - but I can't get the if to work. I'm new with LaTeX, can you help me make it work?

Here's the code:

```
\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
\newcommand{\imgFill}[1]{\begin{center}
\ifnum \measurepage<0.3*\textheigth \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1} 
\else \includegraphics[height=\measurepage,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1} \fi
\end{center}
}
```

Comment: \measurepage is a dimension not a number, so you need to use \ifdim. Beside this: don't show only snippets, a full document is much easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) said, I should have used ifdim instead of ifnum (like I said, I'm new at this). Also, I had a typo (heigth instead of height)

So, If anyone needs this, working code:

```
\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
\newcommand{\imgFill}[1]{\begin{center}
\ifdim \measurepage<0.3\textheight \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1} 
\else \includegraphics[height=\measurepage,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1} \fi
\end{center}
}
```

Comment: Note that the `center` environment adds vertical space as well and is not the right construct to use here. See [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering) for more information.