# Centered, wide float

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Balancing figure that is wider than document's width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/balancing-figure-that-is-wider-than-documents-width)

I have a table which is *just* too wide for the page.

I'd like to be able to float it, centered across the text, but with the float "ignoring" the borders --- i.e. that if it gets wider than the margins it still sits centrally respecting the surrounding text.

Note that compiling the following example leaves everything where it ought to be, except that the tabular is ragged-left, jutting out over the right margin. A good solution would only move the tabular, preserving the caption and all vertical-spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}

\begin{document}

    Blah blah blah blah, said the author, Bob Loblaw on the Bob Loblaw Law Blog. 
    Indeed, that's some bum, Samson, said Sesame Steve, spiritual starter of Sesame Street and sometime successor of some stuff.

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllll}
        A very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very wide table.
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Centered, just-so.}
    \end{table}

    \par

    More text, textifyingly textual in its texterity, contextualises the context with respect left intact.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is basically the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/center-flow-chart-horizontally,  except for the presence of the float.

Comment: @Caramdir: I agree, but even the former question wasn't tagged with {horizontal-alignment} (that is, until a few seconds ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `tabular` inside a `\makebox` command:

```
\makebox[\linewidth]{\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllll}
A very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very wide table.
\end{tabular}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I find that the easiest solution in such cases (provided is a one off) is to just introduce a negative `\hskip` to suit.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
 Blah blah blah blah, said the author, Bob Loblaw on the Bob Loblaw Law Blog. 
 Indeed, that's some bum, Samson, said Sesame Steve, spiritual starter of Sesame Street and sometime successor of some stuff.
 \begin{table}[h]
   \hskip-25pt \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllll}
       A very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very  & very wide table.
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{Centered, just-so.}
\end{table}

\par

    More text, textifyingly textual in its texterity, contextualises the context with respect left intact.

\end{document}
```