# Centering longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I use `longtable` for some very long tables showing evaluation results. They look ok, but I have two problems with them:

1. For some reason, I don't understand, the table seems to be too wide. When I sum up all my `p` values I get to `0.98/textwidth`. Why should this be broader then `/textwidth`?
2. LaTeX writes only across the right margin. Is there any way to tell it to write onto both side margins to center the table?
   I tried the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32726/center-wide-longtable-not-tabular-or-tabularx), but it does not do anything.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.26\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|p{0.12\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{settings} & \textbf{micro-average precision} & \textbf{micro-average recall} & \textbf{micro-average f-score} & \textbf{macro-average precision} & \textbf{macro-average recall} & \textbf{macro-average f-score} \\ \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding 1: You forgot the space between the columns. ~ 16\tabcolsep.

Comment: What does this mean? How much is the space? I don't see any. What is 16\tabcolsep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not advice to get out of the margins if not absolutely necessary. This looks inconsistent and therefore typographically ugly (I am exaggerating). Just reduce each column by the width of its two separators on both sides and you are good to go. I have enlarged the width so that you can use the maximum available. If you reduce a bit, the `[c]` will do the centring for you.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{p{0.28\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}*{6}{p{0.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{settings} & \textbf{micro-average precision} & \textbf{micro-average recall} & \textbf{micro-average f-score} & \textbf{macro-average precision} & \textbf{macro-average recall} & \textbf{macro-average f-score} \\ 
        \bottomrule 
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks right. But I don't understand why. And how do I get my vertical lines back between the columns?

Comment: Just use your MWE and substract the `-2\tabcolsep`. I deleted that lines as I used `booktabs` which I like more. The explanation for what's happening: You are setting `p` columns which act like `parbox`es. You give them a certain width which delimits the possible space for text. As you can see, there is always some white space between those blocks. Those are `\tabcolsep`s which are set in front and behind every column. The sum of all columns plus n times `2\tabcolsep` results in your `\textwidth`

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of taste, but I like [ltxtable (Longtable and tabularx merge)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable).  The usage might seem awkward, but it does a decent job when you want to set the width of a `longtable` to a fix value like `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array,longtable,ltxtable,filecontents}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{long.tex}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.26\textwidth}|*{6}{X|}}
  \hline
  \textbf{settings} 
  & \textbf{micro-average precision} 
  & \textbf{micro-average recall}    & \textbf{micro-average f-score} 
  & \textbf{macro-average precision} & \textbf{macro-average recall} 
  & \textbf{macro-average f-score}   \\ \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\LTXtable{1.0\linewidth}{long.tex}

\end{document}
```

> [image]