# How to center a big table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I have a relatively large table composed the following way

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Backtesting - CFM $\alpha=5\%$, $confidence \ interval = 95\%$ }

\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
Bond & Expected Exceedances & Actual Exceedances & Test Statistic & Critical Value &  p-Value & Decision \\ 
  \hline
1 & 42.00 & 287.00 & 686.63 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
2 & 20.00 & 103.00 & 189.78 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
3 & 20.00 & 101.00 & 182.33 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
4 & 20.00 & 173.00 & 509.53 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
5 & 20.00 & 125.00 & 278.35 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
6 & 20.00 & 119.00 & 253.02 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
7 & 20.00 & 123.00 & 269.81 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
8 & 15.00 & 90.00 & 194.26 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
9 & 10.00 & 50.00 & 84.15 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
10 & 20.00 & 110.00 & 216.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
11 & 9.00 & 39.00 & 55.56 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
12 & 20.00 & 108.00 & 208.85 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
13 & 20.00 & 134.00 & 317.88 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
14 & 20.00 & 174.00 & 514.86 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
15 & 9.00 & 54.00 & 109.55 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
16 & 20.00 & 126.00 & 282.65 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
17 & 20.00 & 165.00 & 470.50 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
18 & 20.00 & 170.00 & 493.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

in which having the \centering command does nothing to the output which is a table that is beyond the right corner of my page. Is there a way to center this table to fit my page? As I mentioned I tested having the \centering command and removing and the output was the same!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See [Centered, wide float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20726) or [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582)

Comment: Optionally you could rewrite your table header, for example by splitting stuff over two rows. Try e.g. adding `\usepackage{siunitx}` (for `S` columns), and modify the start of the table to `\begin{tabular}{*{6}{S}c}  \hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Exceedances} & {Test} & {Critical} &    \\ {Bond} & {Expected} & {Actual} & {Statistic} & {Value} & {$p$-Value} & {Decision}\\ \hline`

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with your table is that quite a few of the entries in the header row are fairly long. I suggest you break them up across two lines. That way, it's only necessary to change the value of `\tabcolsep` -- the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace -- to `5pt` (default value: `6pt`) to make the table fit comfortably inside the text block.

Instead of using `r` for all columns, you may want to use the `S` column type for the middle five columns, since they contain numbers that should be aligned on the respective decimal markers. You may also want to load the `booktabs` package and use its line-drawing macros instead of the generic `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,amsmath,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default value: 6pt 
\caption{Backtesting --- CFM $\alpha=5\%$, $\text{confidence interval} = 95\%$ }
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lSSSSSc@{}}
\toprule
Bond & {Expected} & {Actual}  & {Test} & {Critical} &  {p-value} & Decision \\ 
& {Exceedances} & {Exceedances} & {Statistic} & {Value} \\
\midrule
1 & 42.00 & 287.00 & 686.63 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
2 & 20.00 & 103.00 & 189.78 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
3 & 20.00 & 101.00 & 182.33 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
4 & 20.00 & 173.00 & 509.53 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
5 & 20.00 & 125.00 & 278.35 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
6 & 20.00 & 119.00 & 253.02 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
7 & 20.00 & 123.00 & 269.81 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
8 & 15.00 &  50.00 &  84.15 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
10 & 20.00 & 110.00 & 216.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
11 &  9.00 &  39.00 &  55.56 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
12 & 20.00 & 108.00 & 208.85 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
13 & 20.00 & 134.00 & 317.88 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
14 & 20.00 & 174.00 & 514.86 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
15 &  9.00 &  54.00 & 109.55 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
16 & 20.00 & 126.00 & 282.65 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
17 & 20.00 & 165.00 & 470.50 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
18 & 20.00 & 170.00 & 493.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: the variables "Expected Exceedances" and "Actual Exceedances" are integer-valued, right? If so, one shouldn't show the decimal fractional components of these variables (which, unsurprisingly, are `.00` in all cases). Suppressing the display of the zero decimals may be achieved by setting the option `zero-decimal-to-integer` for columns of type `S`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,amsmath,caption}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Backtesting --- CFM $\alpha=5\%$, $\text{confidence interval} = 95\%$ }
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l
     S[table-format=2.0,zero-decimal-to-integer]
     S[table-format=3.0,zero-decimal-to-integer]
     S[table-format=3.2]
     S[table-format=1.2]
     S[table-format=1.2]
     c @{}}
\toprule
Bond & {Expected} & {Actual}  & {Test} & {Critical} &  {p-value} & Decision \\ 
& {Exceedances} & {Exceedances} & {Statistic} & {Value} \\
\midrule
1 & 42.00 & 287.00 & 686.63 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
2 & 20.00 & 103.00 & 189.78 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
3 & 20.00 & 101.00 & 182.33 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
4 & 20.00 & 173.00 & 509.53 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
5 & 20.00 & 125.00 & 278.35 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
6 & 20.00 & 119.00 & 253.02 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
7 & 20.00 & 123.00 & 269.81 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
8 & 15.00 &  50.00 &  84.15 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
10 & 20.00 & 110.00 & 216.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
11 &  9.00 &  39.00 &  55.56 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
12 & 20.00 & 108.00 & 208.85 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
13 & 20.00 & 134.00 & 317.88 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
14 & 20.00 & 174.00 & 514.86 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
15 &  9.00 &  54.00 & 109.55 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
16 & 20.00 & 126.00 & 282.65 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
17 & 20.00 & 165.00 & 470.50 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
18 & 20.00 & 170.00 & 493.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & Reject H0 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your tabular (thick line only to show the horizontal width), e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\btc{\begin{tabular}{c}}
\def\etc{\end{tabular}}
\def\RejectH0{Reject $H_0$}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{3pt}
\medskip


\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Backtesting - CFM $\alpha=5\%$, $confidence \ interval = 95\%$ }


\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrrrr@{}}
  \hline
Bond & \btc Expected\\ Excee-\\dances \etc & \btc Actual \\Excee-\\dances\etc & \btc Test \\ Stat-\\istic\etc & \btc Crit-\\ical\\ Value\etc &  $p$-Value & Decision \\ 
  \hline
1 & 42.00 & 287.00 & 686.63 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
2 & 20.00 & 103.00 & 189.78 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
3 & 20.00 & 101.00 & 182.33 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
4 & 20.00 & 173.00 & 509.53 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
5 & 20.00 & 125.00 & 278.35 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
6 & 20.00 & 119.00 & 253.02 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
7 & 20.00 & 123.00 & 269.81 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
8 & 15.00 & 90.00 & 194.26 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
9 & 10.00 & 50.00 & 84.15 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
10 & 20.00 & 110.00 & 216.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
11 & 9.00 & 39.00 & 55.56 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
12 & 20.00 & 108.00 & 208.85 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
13 & 20.00 & 134.00 & 317.88 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
14 & 20.00 & 174.00 & 514.86 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
15 & 9.00 & 54.00 & 109.55 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
16 & 20.00 & 126.00 & 282.65 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
17 & 20.00 & 165.00 & 470.50 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
18 & 20.00 & 170.00 & 493.66 & 3.84 & 0.00 & \RejectH0 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]